# Interactive Listbox Tkinter

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter, interactive

I have two listboxes in my user interface, `pbs` and `f`, one next to the other. In `pbs` I have a list of problems which have associated several filenames. I want that when one of the problems from `pbs` is clicked, the corresponding list of files to appear in `f`. I have managed so far to get the index of the selected option from `pbs` and the files appear correctly after the first click, but after several clicks, the files displayed are from other problem than the selected one.

Also I am not sure that I am storing correctly the index. I tried 2 options:

1. storing the name of the problems and of the files in a dictionary - the problem here is that my entries are ordered and I do no want this; I want them exactly in the way I entered them
2. having a list with the problems and a list with the files - the problem here is that I cannot get the index from the listbox as an integer

These are the problems and files (as a dictionary and as lists):

```
problems = {
'pb_1':['1.txt','2.txt','3.txt'],
'pb_a':['a_1.txt','a_2.txt','a_3.txt']
}

problems=['pb_1','pb_a']
files=[['1.txt','2.txt','3.txt'],['a_1.txt','a_2.txt','a_3.txt']]
```

and this is the code:

```
def immd(e):
    for i in problems[pbs.get('active')]:
        f.insert(END,i)

root = Tk()
root.title('Title') 

frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.pack(side=RIGHT)
l3 = Label(frame2, text='Problems:').grid(row=0,column=0)
pbs = Listbox(frame2, height=10)
pbs.grid(row=1,column=0)
for i in problems:
    pbs.insert(END,i)
pbs.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',immd)

l4 = Label(frame2, text='Files:').grid(row=0,column=1)
f = Listbox(frame2, height=10)
f.grid(row=1,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Listbox.curselection`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.curselection-method), you can get the indice of selected items. indices is a list of strings; you should convert the strings to ints.

```
def immd(e):
    indice = pbs.curselection()
    index = int(indice[0])
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Only in the for loop I put `files` instead of `problems`. I also want to know how to erase the output from the second listbox after I make the selection. Can you help me with that or should I edit my question?

Comment: @user1956190, I don't understand what you want. To remove items from the second listbox, use `delete`: `f.delete(0, END)` (put this line before the for loop)